# 6031: return value ignored (getchar()) In visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

It does not affect my code, but I have never seen such issue until I updated my visual studio. I don't know if thats connected, but I am very confused why is there an issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    const int SIZE = 3;

    array<string, SIZE> names = { "S","A","W" };
    array<string, SIZE>::iterator it;

    cout << "names: \n";
    for (it = names.begin(); it != names.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << endl;


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When visual studio was updated, they added a `[[nodiscard]]` attribute to `getchar`. This tells the compiler to warn the user whenever the return value of a function is ignored. You can find out more here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard

In this case, because you're using `getchar` just to prevent the window from closing, you don't need the return value, so you can ignore this warning.

We can silence the warning by explicitly ignoring the return value:

```
(void)getchar(); //Explicitly ignore return value
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `#pragma warning(suppress: 6301)`, but I like your solution much better.  It beats a) configuring  MSVS  "Automatically close console" setting, b) #pragma suppress, or c) just ignoring the silly warning.  It has the added benefit of being portable, and providing a meaningful "statement of intent".  Great suggestion - kudos!

Comment: The solution is correct but `[[nodiscard]]` would be compiler diagnostic C4834. C6000 and upwards are code analysis diagnostics. This one corresponds to the [`_Check_return_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/annotating-function-behavior?view=vs-2019) SAL annotation.

Comment: As of 2020.06.03 I'm trying (void)getchar(); and its not working. My personal fix in this situation is doubling it like getchar();getchar();

Answer (score 0):

My personal fix in this situation, to make a pause in the console, is doubling it like this:

getchar();getchar();

Answer (score 0):

Using `(void)getchar()` causes another analysis warning.

Either suppress using pragmas as mentioned (ugly) or use

```
std::ignore=getchar();
```

I wish they'd have adopted the C# style which was

```
_ = getchar();
```

One could argue that `[[nodiscard]]` was overkill for a function that is often used to accept an enter key at the end of a console app. I would prefer`[[nodiscard]]` to be used sparingly, only when you are required to take action with the result, like freeing memory or interpreting an error code.